# JsonObject to Java object

Tags: java, json

Is it possible to convert jsonobject code to a java object just using JDK and without other libraries like Gson or jackson? Trying to convert the code below to work without JSON.

```
    public void run(){
        boolean flag = true;
        while (flag){
            try {
                JsonObject jsonObject = Json.createReader(bufferedReader).readObject();
                if(jsonObject.containsKey("userID"))
                    System.out.println("["+jsonObject.getString("userID")+"]: "+jsonObject.getString("message"));

            } catch (Exception e) {
                flag = false;
                interrupt();
            }
        } //while loop brackets
    }
```

Comment: You need not another library. What's problem with casting it to Object? Like Object o = (Object) jsonObjec; ?

Comment: @paradoxy I tried but it still doesn't resolve "containsKey", "getString" and "createReader methods".

Answer (score 0):

Create a new class with 2 `String` attributes, then create a new instance with your json object.

```
public class MyObject() {
    private String attribute1;
    private String attribute2;

    public MyObject(String s1, String s2) {
        attribute1 = s1;
        attribute2 = s2;
    }
}
```

```
MyObject myObj = new MyObject(jsonObjec.getString("userID"),jsonObjec.getString("message"));
```

To use it in a loop simple create an array (or `ArrayList`) of that type :

```
ArrayList<MyObject> objects = new ArrayList<>();
```

In your loop :

```
objects.add(new MyObject(jsonObjec.getString("userID"),jsonObjec.getString("message")));
```

Comment: can I do this inside the run method or do I need to call the method inside the run method? The run  above is called by this for loop written here ```for (int i = 0; i < userInput.length ; i++) {
            String[] address = userInput[i].split(":");
            Socket socket = null;
try{
socket = new Socket(address[0], Integer.valueOf(address[1]));
new PeerThread(socket).start(); // instance for peerthread, calling start method.
} catch (Exception e) {
if (socket != null) socket.close();else System.out.println("Invalid Input. Skipping");} }```

Comment: Assuming your `jsonobject` variable contains a correct value, adding the last line I wrote after your printing line should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found an answer:
Created a global variable string array 
`private String[] address;`

and then corrected the code. I think this will work, will troubleshoot later.

````
        boolean flag = true;
        while (flag){
            try {
                Object o = new BufferedReader(bfr).readLine();              /** MIGHT BE PROBLEMS HERE **/
                if(o.equals(address))                                          /**  From here **/
                    System.out.println("["+o.toString()+"]: "+o.toString());
                                                                                /** To here**/
            } catch (Exception e) {
                flag = false;
                interrupt();
            }
        } //while loop brackets
    } // run brackets```
````

Comment: The question title is misleading, do you want to convert JSON to java object or find a way to create an Object without JSON?